# Is there implementation of Git in pure Python?

Tags: python, git, dvcs

Is there implementation of Git in pure Python?

Comment: @Ignacio +1 for your good sense of humor :)

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Comment: @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功 didn't agree on closing this, here question is not about tool exactly, but about implementation.

Comment: @Reishin too broad then :-) Anyways, nowadays I only close vote dupes, nothing else.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found [Dulwich](https://dulwich.io/):

> Dulwich is a pure-Python
> implementation of the Git file formats
> and protocols.
>
> The project is named after the village
> in which Mr. and Mrs. Git live in the
> Monty Python sketch.

Looks like a low-level library, the API did not appear friendly to my eyes, but there's a tutorial on the [Github page](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/master/docs/tutorial/introduction.txt)

Comment: There is a rendered version here: http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/docs/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I think most of the "friendly" (high-level) functionality is in the `porcelain` module in accordance with the way git separates high/low level functionality by name. Also, looks like some args are not sully supported (IE `git log` does not seem to support commit range)

Answer (score 7):

I know that this question is rather old, but I just thought I would add this for the next guy. The accepted answer mentions Dulwich and mentions that it is rather low-level (which is also my opinion). I found [gittle](https://github.com/FriendCode/gittle) which is a high-level wrapper around Dulwich. It's rather easy to use.

#### Install

```
$ pip install gittle
```

Examples (taken from the project's README.md):

#### Clone a repository

```
from gittle import Gittle

repo_path = '/tmp/gittle_bare'
repo_url = 'git://github.com/FriendCode/gittle.git'

repo = Gittle.clone(repo_url, repo_path)
```

#### Init repository from a path

```
repo = Gittle.init(path)
```

#### Get repository information

```
# Get list of objects
repo.commits

# Get list of branches
repo.branches

# Get list of modified files (in current working directory)
repo.modified_files

# Get diff between latest commits
repo.diff('HEAD', 'HEAD~1')
```

#### Commit

```
# Stage single file
repo.stage('file.txt')

# Stage multiple files
repo.stage(['other1.txt', 'other2.txt'])

# Do the commit
repo.commit(name="Samy Pesse", email="samy@friendco.de", message="This is a commit")
```

#### Pull

```
repo = Gittle(repo_path, origin_uri=repo_url)

# Authentication with RSA private key
key_file = open('/Users/Me/keys/rsa/private_rsa')
repo.auth(pkey=key_file)

# Do pull
repo.pull()
```

#### Push

```
repo = Gittle(repo_path, origin_uri=repo_url)

# Authentication with RSA private key
key_file = open('/Users/Me/keys/rsa/private_rsa')
repo.auth(pkey=key_file)

# Do push
repo.push()
```

#### Branch

```
# Create branch off master
repo.create_branch('dev', 'master')

# Checkout the branch
repo.switch_branch('dev')

# Create an empty branch (like 'git checkout --orphan')
repo.create_orphan_branch('NewBranchName')

# Print a list of branches
print(repo.branches)

# Remove a branch
repo.remove_branch('dev')

# Print a list of branches
print(repo.branches)
```

These are just the parts (again pulled from the project's README.md) which I think would be most common use-cases. You should check out the project yourself if you need more than this.

Comment: Note that dulwich nowadays also has a ``dulwich.porcelain`` module, which provides higher-level operations.

Comment: You know, I was actually planning on updating this answer because I was just starting to use `dulwich.porcelain`, they did a good job with it too. Everything I've had to do so far has been really easy.

Comment: Wait, I should say __you__ did a good job. Thanks for the package, it's great!